# How to get more than 20 image when fetching results from Google Image?

Tags: php, curl

The script below fetches images from Google, it get only 20 images of the page specified in $page variable.

I didn't figure out why it's getting exactly 20 result and how can i change this value to be larger, to display 100 first images for example

```
<?php


// Image sizes
define ('GIS_LARGE', 'l');
define ('GIS_MEDIUM', 'm');
define ('GIS_ICON', 'i');
define ('GIS_ANY', '');

// Image types
define ('GIS_FACE', 'face');
define ('GIS_PHOTO', 'photo');
define ('GIS_CLIPART', 'clipart');
define ('GIS_LINEART', 'lineart');

function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}


function googleImageSearch ($query, $page = 1, $size = GIS_ANY, $type = GIS_ANY)
{

$retVal = array();

// Get the search results page


$response = get_data("http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&q=" . urlencode ($query) . '&imgsz=' . $size . '&imgtype=' . $type . '&start=' . (($page - 1) * 21));

// Extract the image information. This is found inside of a javascript call to setResults
preg_match('/\<table class=\"images_table\"(.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/table\>/is', $response, $match);

if (isset($match[2])) {

    // Grab all the arrays
    preg_match_all('/\<td(.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/td\>/', $match[2], $m);

    foreach ($m[2] as $item) {

        // List of expressions used to grab all our info
        $info = array(
            'resultLink' => '\<a href=\"(.*?)\"',
            'source' => 'imgurl=(.*?)&amp;',
            'title' => '\<br\/\>(.*?)\<br\/\>([\d]+)',
            'width' => '([\d]+) &times;',
            'height' => '&times; ([\d]+)',
            'type' => '&nbsp;-([\w]+)',
            'size' => ' - ([\d]+)',
            'thumbsrc' => 'src="(.*?)"',
            'thumbwidth' => 'width="([\d]+)"',
            'thumbheight' => 'height="([\d]+)"',
            'domain' => '\<cite title="(.*?)"\>'
        );

        $t = new stdClass;
        $t->thumb = new stdClass;
        foreach ($info as $prop => $expr) {
            if (preg_match('/' . $expr . '/is', $item, $m)) {
                $value = 'title' == $prop ? str_replace(array('<b>', '</b>'), '', $m[1]) : $m[1];

                // Thumb properties go under the thumb object
                if (0 === strpos($prop, 'thumb')) {
                    $prop = str_replace('thumb', '', $prop);
                    $t->thumb->$prop = $value;
                } else {
                    $t->$prop = $value;
                }

                // Nicey up the google images result url
                if ('resultLink' == 'resultLink') {
                    $t->resultLink = 'http://images.google.com' . $t->resultLink;
                }

            }
        }

        $retVal[] = $t;

    }

}

return $retVal;

}
```

Where is the line of code that tells the script to get 20 images ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't. The script is fetching results from standard version of Google images and it has no option to change results per page. The only thing you can do is to request five times to have 100 images in all.

**Update**: To keep updating appending the images just use '+' operator. Like,

```
$image = array();

for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ )
     $image += googleImageSearch ($query, $page = 1, $size = GIS_ANY, $type = GIS_ANY);
```

Beware, if you are not clever to conceal your request, or google is suspicious of automated request you are likely to encounter this page.

[image]

Comment: Me too i was thinking about calling the function again and again, could you please show me how can i make this function do its work 2  times so it append every time to $retVal[] before returning it ? 
I'm sucked on this for three days without a solution. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the google API.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

As mentioned by @shubham, you will surely end up on this page as google checks for bots.